# Reading a multiline record into Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, fixed-width

I have an earthquake data I want to read into a Pandas dataframe. Data for each earthquake is spread over 5 fixed-format lines, and the format for each of the 5 lines is different. Some fields include variable whitespaces, so I can't just do a delimited read.

Is there an elegant way to parse that with read_fwf (or something else)? I think nesting loops with chunksize=1 might work but it's not very clean. Or I could reformat the file to cat each 5 line block out to a single line; but I'd rather use the original file.

Here's he first earthquake as an example:

```
MLI  1976/01/01 01:29:39.6 -28.61 -177.64  59.0 6.2 0.0 KERMADEC ISLANDS REGION
M010176A         B:  0    0   0 S:  0    0   0 M: 12   30 135 CMT: 1 BOXHD:  9.4
CENTROID:     13.8 0.2 -29.25 0.02 -176.96 0.01  47.8  0.6 FREE O-00000000000000
26  7.680 0.090  0.090 0.060 -7.770 0.070  1.390 0.160  4.520 0.160 -3.260 0.060
V10   8.940 75 283   1.260  2  19 -10.190 15 110   9.560 202 30   93  18 60   88
```

Comment: your question is too vague. Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I do not believe you can use any standard reader for this data. You'll end up reading and parsing the file line by line into a list of dictionaries and then building a dataframe from it.

Comment: Thanks DYZ, that's what I'm doing.